# How to set restrictions on usage of selected services at space level in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I need some help on creating space quota plans with higher granularity in the restrictions.

I can create a space quota plan that either allows or disallows use of paid services. If I create a space quota plan that disallows paid services and assign it to a space, I will not be able to use even some of the most common boiler plates (such as Node.js Cloudant DB Web Starter, Java Cloudant Web Starter, etc) in that space.

However, I would like to create a space quota plan such that I allow the use of only free service plans and selected paid plans like the boiler plates.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Boilerplates are kind of a shorthand for provisioning several services and a sample app. It is similar to what you could do with a "Deploy to Bluemix".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You can't select specific services or boilerplates in space quota definition.
You can specify:

```
* number of routes
* number of services
* memory
* memory instance
* show all services or only free services
```

You can 'create' a boilerplates combining specific runtime and\or services.

Comment: That is what I did using the ceate-space-quota API.  I wish there were more options to control at the service level. Something like an ACL.  Allow or disallow a service for a space.